# Why is the complexity poor for my pair finder and what to improve

Tags: java, arrays, performance, linked-list, time-complexity

Was completing this challenge and I ended up scoring poorly due to my solutions complexity, I had a result of `O(n2)`, but I can't figure out why since I feel like it should run faster, and code wise it is very compact and efficient line wise:
task brief:
[image]

what I was asked to do:

***My code is as follows:***

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        LinkedList <Integer> checkedNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i< A.length; i++) {
            // check against what we have found before
            boolean foundNumber = false;
            for(int x=0; x <checkedNumbers.size(); x++) {
                if (A[i] == checkedNumbers.get(x)) {
                    checkedNumbers.remove(x);
                    foundNumber = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(foundNumber == false) {
                checkedNumbers.add(A[i]);
            }
        }
        int result = checkedNumbers.pop();
        return result ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Time complexity of your code is O(n^4) (worst case). `get` and `remove` in `LinkedList` have linear complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `ArrayList` and nested loops would give you quadratic time complexity (`O(n^2)`). Using a `LinkedList` would make it even worse, since (as commented by talex), `get` andremove`take`O(n)`time in`LinkedList`, so your code has time complexity of`O(n^4)`.

If you used a `HashSet` instead, it would take `O(1)` time to add, remove and find elements, so the total running time will be linear (`O(n)`).

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> checkedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i=0; i< A.length; i++) {
        if (!checkedNumbers.add(A[i])) { // try to add the element
            checkedNumbers.remove(A[i]); // remove it if it's already in the Set
        }
    }
    return checkedNumbers.iterator().next();
}
```

As suggested in the comments, the code my be improved a bit:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> checkedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer number : A) {
        if (!checkedNumbers.add(number)) { // try to add the element
            checkedNumbers.remove(number); // remove it if it's already in the Set
        }
    }
    return checkedNumbers.iterator().next();
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation and algorithm; I *might* suggest using `for (int v : A)` over an explicit index (but this is very readable as is).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch one *might* also consider declaring the loop variable as `Integer` to avoid boxing it twice.

Answer (score 5):

There is a trick to solve this without any complex data structures:

```
int v = 0;
for (int a : A) {
  v ^= a; // Compound exclusive or.
}
return v;
```

The compound exclusive-or assignment operator used here will "flip" the bits in `v` corresponding to bits which have the value 1 in `a`.

This works because `a ^ a ≡ 0` (and `a ^ b ≡ b ^ a`, and `(a ^ b) ^ c ≡ a ^ (b ^ c)`, and `a ^ 0 ≡ a`), so the bits of observing `a` the first time are cancelled out by the bits of observing `a` a second time.

The only bits which will be set in `v` at the end are the ones from the unpaired element.

For example, if the array contains `[a, b, a, b, u]` (so `u` is the unpaired element):

```
  a ^ b ^ a ^ b ^ u
= (a ^ a) ^ (b ^ b) ^ u
= 0 ^ 0 ^ u
= u
```